# Use the width of the body, not the element

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="tst">
    Hello. 
    <div id="ln">
     Red line should be not just in tst element, but in all body.            
    </div>
</div>​

#tst {
 width: 200px;
 margin: 10px auto;            
}
#ln {
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 2px solid red;    
}
​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hXEe7/

Is it possible to make red line 100% width of the body without putting #ln element outside #tst? Line must be in #ln element, it's just an example. Thanks.

Comment: no, you can only set a child in relation to the parent, not to the parents parent. But you could `ln` move out of `tst`

Comment: why don't you use #ln outside of #tst?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/sinanakyazici/hXEe7/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, provided that no other element above it is positioned, is to make the line's position absolute like this:

```
#ln {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This will only work of there is no other positioned element all the way up to the body. If another element is positioned, it will serve as a frame of reference

Comment: I know, that's why i wrote so.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ln {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;   
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Will take `<div id="ln">` out of the regular document flow, and will use the `body`'s width.

Comment: Your answer is same with  @Alexander Christiansson's answer.

Comment: I did not know he was righting an answer. When I came to this question there were no answers.

Comment: When there is an answer while you typing an answer, the stackoverflow informs you on upper side of textarea.

Comment: Ok I did not know that, will watch for that in the future.

Comment: @phpechousername I gave you +1, don't worry.